# Quando abbiamo smesso di gire?

Tags: vocabulary, history

Leggendo vari testi rinascimentali sono rimasto sorpreso da quanto fosse comune il verbo *gire* (sinonimo di *andare*), che è ormai completamente caduto fuori dall'uso corrente, con l'eccezione del participio passato *gita*. Però il fatto che *gita* sia termine d'uso assai comune, mi fa pensare che *gire* possa esser sopravvissuto fino a relativamente tardi.

> **Q** A che punto dell'evoluzione della lingua italiana abbiamo smesso di usare il verbo *gire*?

Comment: E si usava anche *ire*. È vero che si usa ancora in Toscana?

Comment: @Charo Non che io mi ricordi dai miei anni a Pisa (al contrario di *codesto* che si usa davvero e fa un effetto molto strano ai non toscani), ma la Toscana è grande e ci sono molte variazioni.

Comment: @Charo: Non so la Toscana, ma so che si usa in romanesco, anche se minacciato da _annà_.

Comment: @Charo Confermo, ed inoltre "ire" si usa anche nel Mezzogiorno. _Me n'aggia ì_!

Comment: @DenisNardin: Ho potuto chiederlo a un toscano e mi ha detto che si usa ancora in campagna, ma non in città.

Comment: Si usa in alcuni dialetti. Di certo nelle Marche, a Cingoli. Trattasi di derivazione da "itus", come la forma "jire, jito" a pochi chilometri.

Comment: @AlfonsoValori: Non capisco bene: in che senso “gire” “trattasi di derivazione da ‘itus’”? Semmai è “itus” che è una voce di “(g)ire”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secondo quello che si spiega nel libro *L'italiano scomparso. Grammatica della lingua che non c'è più*, di Vittorio Coletti, questo verbo sembra aver cominciato a cadere in disuso ai tempi di Manzoni.

Sulla pagina 39 di questo libro si legge, a proposito di verbi scomparsi:

> *gire/ire* (andare: «mostratene la via di gire al monte» *Purg*. II 60, «e la prora ire in giù, com'altrui piacque» *Inf*. XXVI 141; «Dove sei gita [...] dolcezza mia?» Leopardi, *Ricordanze* 138; Manzoni nei *Promessi sposi* corregge «se n'era ito» del '27 in «se n'era andato» del '40)

E anche nella pagina 130:

> Il significato del participio passato di *andare* è stato espresso
> nella lingua antica e letteraria e anche nel toscano popolare pure attraverso quello del verbo disusato *ire* (un puro latinismo), volgarizzato all'infinito anche in *gire*, per cui quindi *ito* e *gito*: «Ito è così e va sanza riposo» (*Purg*. XI 124), «e rallegrasi il cielo, ov'ello è gito» (Petrarca, *Canz*. XCII 14). Lo userà ancora Leopardi nelle *Ricordanze*.

Anche Luca Serianni nel libro *Parola di Dante* spiega:

> *Andare/gire*. Il verbo fondamentale in italiano è *andare*, ma anche *gire* era diffuso originariamente nella lingua viva, sia pure solo in alcune forme; presto si è specializzato nella lingua poetica, sopravvivendo, in particolare nell’infinito e nel participio passato, fino a tutto l’Ottocento<sup>[15]</sup>. In Dante gli esempi di *gire* sono all’incirca un ottavo di quelli di *andare* (per *gire* non c’è nessuna ricorrenza di congiuntivo presente e condizionale, comunque molto rari in qualsiasi testo).

> <sup>[15] Cfr. Luca Serianni, *La lingua poetica italiana. Grammatica e testi*, Roma, Carocci, 2009, pp. 227-229.</sup>